# PSN API where I can get data of purchased games

Tags: web-applications, userinfo, playstation

I'm wondering if there's any way where I can get the data of all purchased games from a user on PlayStation - specifically my purchased games. I know this data is private.

When I look for PSN APIs I only find about trophies, usernames, etc.
Is there any way to get this info, or is it sensitive info maybe?
I'm very new on these things so please bare with me!

My idea is to create an app for personal use where I can browse my purchased games and have an option to choose randomly a game among those.